# How to Retrieve User Tweets from Twitter Using XML and Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am trying to retrived data from Twitter XML URL. here i wrote the code for it. but it is not working.
could you tell me how to retrive Tweets and user name from the URL using XML and AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax(
{  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=rushijogle",  
    data: "whatever",
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    success: function(xml){

                var xmlDoc;

                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
                }
                else // Internet Explorer
                {
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = "false";
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
                }

                var $response = $(xmlDoc);

             var data = $response.find("favorited").text()

        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Demo Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/be9y6/

Thanx in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter [does not support XML anymore](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview). Also, it is uncler to me the reason why you're using `POST`, if that's a `GET`- but it might be that I am not acquainted with the demo you're trying to use as source. Anyhow, if you're trying to post a favourite (it's what I see from your code), you should switch to json and their API 1.1 protocols. They don't support XML
I hope this helps.